# Where is the Azure AD B2C Graph API Reference?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

Where is the api reference for B2C in the [Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/)?

Is it [this section](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/azure_ad_overview)?  Maybe there is not a single section?  I say that b/c the [demo app](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet) uses api's under the [user section](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_post_users) and api's under the [Azure AD -> Applications](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure AD Graph doesn't do any special provision for Azure AD B2C, it's the same set of API you'd use for Azure AD. The main difference is that in absence of consent features, all access is performed via application level credentials.

Comment: To add to Vittorio's answer, [here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) a nice code sample that demonstrates how to get tokens with Azure AD B2C for the Azure AD Graph API.